# jquery toggleSlide() not sliding

Tags: jquery

i have a toggle slide which basically it just hiding and showing, it's not sliding up and down like it should.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(event){
        $('.togglable tr:not(:first-child)').hide();

        $('a.toggleSwitch').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().parent().siblings('tr').slideToggle("fast");
        });
    });
</script>
```

and the html...

```
<table class="togglable">
    <tr><td><a class="toggleSwitch" href="#">Click me</a></td></tr>
    <tr><th>Part No</th><th>Description</th></tr>
    <tr><td>12345</td><td>Description1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>12344</td><td>Description2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>12343</td><td>Description3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>12342</td><td>Description4</td></tr>
</table>
```

just getting to grips with jquery, so any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4FLBv/))

```
<a class="toggleSwitch" href="#">Click me</a>
    <div class="togglable">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Part No
                </th>
                <th>
                    Description
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    12345
                </td>
                <td>
                    Description1
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    12344
                </td>
                <td>
                    Description2
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    12343
                </td>
                <td>
                    Description3
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    12342
                </td>
                <td>
                    Description4
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (event) {
            $('.togglable').hide();

            $('a.toggleSwitch').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('.togglable').slideToggle("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Actually the markup you are trying to slide doesn't have enough space vertically to look nicer when it slides.

Comment: thanks, but i need this to work with multiple tables on the same page, which is why i did triggered from within the table... if i did it this way then i would need a function for each table that i want to shrink?